# Using multiple Tensorflow Restored Graphs and Sessions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am attempting to reload a session and graph in a function to process more data. I keep getting errors as `using uninitialized variable`.

I have tried to reuse my GRU cell with no avail.

I am currently resorting to loading each model into a dameon thread and having it look for an empty list to run data and return to list instead of a function return the predictions.

```
    model = {
    'chunk_size' : 9,
    'num_chunk' : 31,
    'rnn_size' : 18,
    'rnn_classes' : 2
}
graphx = tf.Graph()
sess = tf.Session(graph= graphx)
save_path = ('models/rnn_1d/rnn_1d.ckpt')

def loadModel(model, graphx, sess, save_path):
    with graphx.as_default():
        chunk_size = model['chunk_size']
        num_chunks = model['num_chunk'] #need to update to num_chunks in model creator
        rnn_size = model['rnn_size']
        rnn_classes = model['rnn_classes']

        X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, num_chunks, chunk_size])
        Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

        def rnn_model(x):
            weight_initializer = tf.variance_scaling_initializer(mode="fan_avg", distribution="uniform", scale=1)
            bias_initializer = tf.zeros_initializer()
            layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(weight_initializer([rnn_size, rnn_classes])),
                    'biases':tf.Variable(bias_initializer([rnn_classes]))}


            x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
            x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, chunk_size])
            x = tf.split(x, num_chunks, 0)

            lstm_cell = rnn_cell.GRUCell(rnn_size)
            outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

            output = tf.add(tf.matmul(outputs[-1], layer['weights']), layer['biases'])
            return output
        prediction = rnn_model(X)
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(sess, save_path)
    print(' loaded')
    return sess, graphx

def feedModel(model, sess, graphx, Set):
    with graphx.as_default():
        chunk_size = model['chunk_size']
        num_chunks = model['num_chunk'] #need to update to num_chunks in model creator
        rnn_size = model['rnn_size']
        rnn_classes = model['rnn_classes']

        X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, num_chunks, chunk_size])
        Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

        def rnn_model(x):
            weight_initializer = tf.variance_scaling_initializer(mode="fan_avg", distribution="uniform", scale=1)
            bias_initializer = tf.zeros_initializer()
            layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(weight_initializer([rnn_size, rnn_classes])),
                    'biases':tf.Variable(bias_initializer([rnn_classes]))}


            x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
            x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, chunk_size])
            x = tf.split(x, num_chunks, 0)

            lstm_cell = rnn_cell.GRUCell(rnn_size, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
            outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

            output = tf.add(tf.matmul(outputs[-1], layer['weights']), layer['biases'])
            return output

        prediction = rnn_model(X)

        prediction = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={X: Set})
        return prediction


sess, graphx = loadModel(model, graphx, sess, save_path)

print(feedModel(model, sess, graphx, np.ones((1,31,9)) ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks you're totally (and *I think* unnecessarily) recreating your model in `feedModel`.  All of those ops are already defined in `graphx`, which you pass in.  You presumably initialize those in some other code (the one that saves the session) using something like `tf.global_variables_initializer().run()`.  The new variables that you define here won't be initialized- I suspect that's why you're getting the `uninitialized variable` error.

It looks to me like `feedModel` should simply look like this:

```
def feedModel(model, sess, graphx, Set):
    with graphx.as_default():
        prediction = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={X: Set})
        return prediction
```